# error using swank-cdt for debug clojure : " unabled to add tools.jar to classpath"

Tags: debugging, clojure, leiningen

I'm learning how debug a clojure app...I've tried several tools and no one has convinced me..now I'm trying swank-cdt which is based in CDT...I've read the instruction here:

http://georgejahad.com/clojure/swank-cdt.html

I've added my dev-dependencies to my lein project (in my case clojure-source "1.2.1"  because I'm using clojure 1.2.1...)

I've run lein deps..and lein install...elein swank for use repl, and slime-connect for connect my repl...so far so good...I've used (use 'debugproject.core) run well...

now..when try (use 'swank.cdt) I get in my stacktrace:

com.sun.jdi.Bootstrap
  [Thrown class java.lang.ClassNotFoundException]

and inside my repl :

warning: unabled to add tools.jar to classpath. This may cause CDT initialization to fail.

what am I doing wrong!??

thanks for your patience and for read all my post :D
and many thanks if you can help me

Answer (score 1):

Swank-clojure 1.4.0, released yesterday, automatically sets up the tools.jar crap for you.  You don't need to symlink or copy anything.

Answer (score 0):

I've copied tools.jar into lib/dev